# tensorflow porting to android devices

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have a question about tensorflow porting to android devices. When I was in centos, using bazel compiler generated apk file, suggesting the following error:

ERROR: /data/tensorflow-master/WORKSPACE:37:1: syntax error at 'tf_workspace': expected,
ERROR: /data/tensorflow-master/WORKSPACE:44:1: non-keyword arg after keyword arg.
ERROR: error loading package 'external': Failed to parse WORKSPACE file.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.242s

The following is the 37-44 line of the WORKSPACE file:

Please add all new TensorFlow dependencies in workspace.bzl.

37 tf_workspace ()

38

39 new_http_archive (

40 name = "inception5h",

41 build_file = "models.BUILD",

42 url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip",

43 sha256 = "d13569f6a98159de37e92e9c8ec4dae8f674fbf475f69fe6199b514f756d4364"

44)

I ask you have encountered similar problems? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, this is how I fixed it:

```
# Uncomment and update the paths in these entries to build the Android demo.
android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk",
    api_level = 24,
#    # Ensure that you have the build_tools_version below installed in the
#    # SDK manager as it updates periodically.
    build_tools_version = "25.0.3",
#    # Replace with path to Android SDK on your system
    path = "/home/yours/Android/Sdk/",
) #my mistake #) --> )
#
# Android NDK r12b is recommended (higher may cause issues with Bazel)
android_ndk_repository(
    name="androidndk",
    path="/home/yours/android-ndk-r12b/",
#    # This needs to be 14 or higher to compile TensorFlow.
#    # Note that the NDK version is not the API level.
    api_level=14)
```